# Anchor slow scroll fixed header

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to use a smooth scroll for the anchors on the page.
Therefore I use the following code:

```
<script>
$(document).on('click', 'a', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();

    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $( $.attr(this, 'href') ).offset().top
    }, 500);
});
</script>
```

The only problem is that I have a fixed header, with a height of 88px. So when clicking on the anchor, it currently scrolls to far.

How can I extent my code so it will work correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know that your fixed header will **always** have a height of 88px, you can simply add that value to the final scroll position to make space for that :)

```
$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $( $.attr(this, 'href') ).offset().top + 88
}, 500);
```

If the fixed header height might change, you will want to check it's outerHeight and add that to the offset. Assuming that the fixed header's jQuery object is stored as `$fixedHeader`:

```
$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $( $.attr(this, 'href') ).offset().top + $fixedHeader.outerHeight()
}, 500);
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to add 88px to the scrollTop ?

```
<script>
$(document).on('click', 'a', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();

    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $( $.attr(this, 'href') ).offset().top + 88;
    }, 500);
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

CSS ONLY solution

```
html{
   scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
[id] { scroll-margin-top: 88px }
```

This css sets the scroll behavior to smooth and sets all anchors on page to have a scroll-margin-top property, which snaps scrolling to the set position.